# Wrong confirm

Tags: java

Добрый день.Пробую силы в java. И вот такая ошибка меня сбила с толку.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>Untitled Document</title><script> function check(){ var fName = document.getElementById('fname'); var fLname = document.getElementById('lname');var fPhone = document.getElementById('phone');var fAdress = document.getElementById('adress');var fEmail = document.getElementById('email');var fConfemail = document.getElementById('confemail'); if (fEmail != fConfemail ){     alert('wrong confirm');     return false; }if (fName.value.length<3){ alert('Логин не может быть меньше 3-х символов!'); return false; } if (fLname.value.length<5){ alert('Пароль не может быть меньше 5-ти символов!'); return false; }if(fPhone.value.length<10){alert('Phone cant be less 10');return false;}alert('Регистрация завершена!'); return true; } </script></head><body><form onsubmit="return check()"> Логин: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/> Пароль: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/>Phone:<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />Adress:<input type="text" id="adress" name="adress" />Email:<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />Confirm Email:<input type="confemail" id="confemail" name="confemail" oblur="function check()" /> <input type="submit" value="регистрация" name="submit"/> </form> </body></html>
```

все поля заполняются если email введен повторно правильно и все условия соблюдены то результат - Регистрация завершена!Буду благодарен если поможете с этим вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не путайте java и javascript! Это два совершенно разных языка.
2. Я так полагаю, что в переменные **fEmail** и **fConfemail** вы хотели получить не объект, а значение поля? Ну так и используйте **value**:

> var fEmail =document.getElementById('email').value;

1. А для того, чтобы в следующий раз быстрее разобраться с проблемой, активнее используйте alert, в вашем случае вы гораздо быстрее бы разобрались сами, если бы временно заменили строку      **alert('wrong confirm');** на **alert(fEmail);**